# Is a curve important on a 34in UW monito/LCD?

Tags: display

How important is a curve for a 34in UW monitor? The reason i'm asking is because i found a great deal on a 34in UW panel but its flat (not curved). So is a curve in the panel that important? For context i'm not a gamer. I'm a web developer. Movies on the UW might be nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not terribly important. The curve helps in situations where you will be close to the monitor and need to reduce eye strain and travel. As long as you are a decent distance away from the display, a curve is totally unnecessary for either picture fidelity or usability.